# What is the use of take in take precautions?

Tags: word-meaning

That's a question from my friend who has been doing research about the verb *take* recently. He uses Cambridge Dictionary and they list 17 uses in total (for only the verb). [link] (http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/take#british-1-1-3)

I read all 17 uses but couldn't figure out which use it is. I thought it was *need* or *accept*.

I also ran into this link which says that the meaning of *take* depends on the words that go with it in some specific expressions. So, if I cannot find an exact use of *take*, which meaning should I refer to? I just thought about *accept*.

Comment: [link] (http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/take)
The second link has been added.

Answer (score 2):

In the phrase

> take precautions

"take" has the meaning of "hold *(with you)*" or "use"

> Take precautions when going into the wild.
>   *Use precautions when going into the wild.*
>
> Take notice of anything strange that you see or hear.
>   *Pay close attention to anything strange that you see or hear.*